# In python, how to use split('_') on a column with dtype object?

Tags: python, pandas, split

I am working on a data frame whose one column is of type object:

example: `name  36512 non-null object`

I have tried the following with no success

```
> name_str = autos['name'].to_string()
> print(type(name_str))   # this makes the name_str as type string
> autos['name'] = name_str  # putting it back in the data frame brought it back to type object
```

Also, tried the following:

```
> import json
> autos['name'] = json.dumps(name_str)
```

My goal is to split the first two words using `split('_')`, but unable to do so unless the type is string

example: `BMW_740i_4_4_Liter_HAMANN_UMBAU_Mega_Optik`

output: `['BMW', '740i']` in a new column

Comment: It worked. The column type is still object, but the split('_') worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['BMW_740i_4_4_Liter_HAMANN_UMBAU_Mega_Optik']})

df['new'] = df['name'].str.split('_').str[:2]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                         name          new
0  BMW_740i_4_4_Liter_HAMANN_UMBAU_Mega_Optik  [BMW, 740i]
```

Note that a column of strings is considered an "object" dtype in pandas so you should have the right dtype already